# NodeJS: can't access function parameter inside try/catch if use await

Tags: node.js, babeljs

I test this code on either nodejs 8 (without babel) & babel, and both of them show same effects.

```
async function refreshBalance({ user }) {
  console.log(user) // show correct variable
  try {
    console.log(user) // throw error: variable not defined
    const user = await findObject('_User', user.id, {
      sessionToken: user.getSessionToken(),
    })

    return {
      balance: user.get('balance'),
      balanceUpdatedAt: user.get('updatedAt'),
    }
  }
  catch (error) {
    return formattedError(error)
  }
}
```

but it doesn't throw error if I remove `await` like this:

```
async function refreshBalance({ user }) {
  console.log(user) // show correct variable
  try {
    console.log(user) // show correct variable, no error

    return true
  }
  catch (error) {
    return formattedError(error)
  }
}
```

I know I can cache variable like this to make it work:

```
async function refreshBalance({ user }) {
  const theUser = user
  try {
    console.log(theUser) // `theUser` variable is safe, `user` variable will throw error
    const user = await findObject('_User', theUser.id, {
      sessionToken: user.getSessionToken(),
    })

    return {
      balance: theUser.get('balance'),
      balanceUpdatedAt: theUser.get('updatedAt'),
    }
  }
  catch (error) {
    return formattedError(error)
  }
}
```

I'm curious why first approach show an error? I already search google & didn't find any answer.

**EDIT:**

It throws an error if `user` is an object, and it didn't throw an error if `user` is either string or number.

Here is how I execute the function:
`refreshBalance({ user: { id: '123 '} })`

Comment: Do you realize that `const user` is redefining a new variable `user` which "hides" the function argument named `user` in the scope in which the new variable is defined?  I can't really tell what your question is asking.  Which function parameter can you not access and where can you not access it?

Comment: Ah, thanks @jfriend00, you are correct. I can make it work by rename variable to other name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Making my comment into an answer since it seemed to work for you.

Your definition of `const user = ...` is "hiding" or "overriding" the function parameter of the same name making it so the function parameter is not reachable in the scope where the `const user` is defined.

The simplest solution would be to just change the name of one of those two variables to something else so they do not conflict.